# any reasons why the snackbar isn't working

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.snackbar(
                'app',
                'app',
                snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                titleText: const Text('another'),
                messageText: const Text('Another mssg'),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('Booking Calender'),
          ),
```

any reason why snackbar is not working

Comment: Hello Sir, are you using GetMaterialApp on top of your widget? Does it show any error in the console?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post the full code but try changing the MaterialApp() widget to GetMaterialApp() widget.

Comment: if this answer helped you please mark it as solved for other people

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the Main File In MaterialApp() widget to GetMaterialApp() widget.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).